# mysql: how do i make a copy of the entire database?

Tags: sql, mysql

how do i make an exact duplicate copy of a database in mysql?

```
create database test1 from test ???????
```

if this is not possible, how do i copy a table from one database into another"?

Comment: I think this belongs at ServerFault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't per say. You need to create the new database, create the tables and then do inserts i.e. insert into INSERT INTO `newdatabase`.`table1` SELECT * FROM `olddatabase`.`table1`;

Alternately, you could do a full database dump to a sql file and then dump this file into a new database.

A third option (easiest really if you have it) is PhpMyAdmin's copy database function. It creates the new database, the tables and inserts the data all automatically.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is taking a dump from the source db and importing it into another db, like this:

```
mysqldump src_db > src.sql
mysql dest_db < src.sql
```

Comment: doable in essentials, but he can have issues if there are any large blobs in the db...

Comment: a blob is a binary large object - check out the wiki:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_(computing)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqlhotcopy db_name /path/to/new_directory
```

Keep in mind that the users will be blocked from updating tables while they are being copied, since mysqlhotcopy locks them.

I don't know if mysqlhotcopy locks them all at once or one at a time.  If it locks them all at once, then all users will be blocked until the copy completes.

If it locks them one at a time while users are modifying them, you have a risk of the tables getting out of sync with each other.  Like this:

mysqlhotcopy locks table a, and begins copy of table a
client attaches to database and tries to update tables a and c.  It is temporarily blocked because of lock on table a.
mysqlhotcopy completes copy, unlocks table a, locks table b, and begins copy of table b
client makes related updates to tables a and c.
mysqlhotcopy completes copy, unlocks table b, locks table c, and copies table c

The problem is that the copied version of table a is from before the client's modification, and the version of table c is from after the client's modification, which puts the backup
in an inconsistent state.

**Update**
I just looked at mysqlhotcopy (MySQL 4.1.9).  It locks all the tables at once.